# Namespaces and classes missing from referenced DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add a reference to a project ("Geometry") that lives in another solution ("Bar Solution") into another solution ("Foo Solution"). Any project in Bar Solution (the home of the Geometry's source code) can import Geometry and use its features with no problem; however, when I add the DLL to Foo Solution, it imports fine, but the Object Browser shows it containing no namespaces or classes.

Has anyone experienced this problem or otherwise know of a solution? I can't find any information on SO or more generally, le Goog.

**Object Browser of Foo Solution:**

[image]

**Bar's Solution Explorer:**

[image]

**Some code from Foo which is trying to use "Geometry":**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Geometry; // Error: "The type or namespace name 'Geometry' could not be found
                //   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

namespace Lever
{
    public partial class LeverGUI : Form
    {
        public LeverGUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a snippet of what the namespace looks like in the project in regards to what the assemblyname is and the default namespace is..?

Comment: You don't see metadata at all ?

Comment: @AlexH No metadata that I'm aware of. I attached a snapshot from my Object Browser to the question.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm not exactly sure I understand what you're looking for, but the namespace is actually called "Geometry" and the project containing its source code is also called "Geometry". It is being imported into a project called "Lever". Is this the information you were looking for?

Comment: how about showing what the class looks like can you do a screen shot of the your solution explorer as well can you also show some code of how you are trying to consume and or create an Instance of Geometry..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I added the requested details. Please let me know if I can provide you with more information.

Comment: It looks like you have your namespace as Lever if the namespace for geometry is Lever then you need to fully qualify the Geometry in your using for example using Lever.Geometry or change the namespace for the ColorfulRectF.cs to be Geometry..

Comment: What versions of .NET are each of the solutions? New can reference old, but old cannot reference new. I have seen this behavior in solution explorer when, say, a .net 2.0 project is references a .net 4.0 project....

Comment: @DJKRAZE I'm having a little difficulty understanding your suggestion. Could you pose it as an answer with a code snippet?

Comment: Perhaps one is using .Net Framework 4/4.5 Client Profile and the other is using the full version. Check it in the project's properties.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis Hmm, nope, both projects have ".NET Framework 4" listed as their Target framework. :/

Comment: @weberc2 Are you by any chance obfuscating your assemblies?

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis Could you please be more specific? I don't really know what it would mean to "obfuscate an assembly".

Comment: @weberc2 Obfuscation is the process of changing symbol names, namespaces etc. of an assembly using a tool so that it is harder to reverse-engineer. Apparently this is not the case here. Have you tried adding the whole Geometry project to the other solution? Remember that projects can be shared between solutions.